# C#:inputting txt file

Tags: c#, arrays, file-io

Im building an app that inputs a txt file, and as an output it makes a txt file with all words and count how many times each word has been repeated. I have taken care of counting words but i have an issue with reading a file. To be more precise when i write a test txt file and when i use Enter to go to next line it doesnt work well in app. Ill post the code and results to make things clear.

```
    string text = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\\Users\\derka\\Documents\test.txt");

        string[] array = text.Split(' ', ',', '.', ':', '\t');
```

and the output is

hello, 2
world, 2
world
coo, 1
cooo, 1

The expected result was to see world ,3. I also tried using Regex but i cant seem to figure out how to fill an array using foreach loop that i used for regex. Suggestions? Below are the contents of the file i used for testing

> hello world world hello world
>
> coo cooo

Comment: Careful with those tags...

Comment: Some debug would help - look at your "array" variable, look and check what it split your text into.. as you read your text you havent split on lines.. so hence it has "world coo" as a word

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that you ignore line-breaks in your *Split* call.
So you should add *\r* and *\n* to your call.

```
string[] array = text.Split(' ', ',', '.', ':', '\t', '\n', '\r');
```

This will return empty strings in the array because if the line-break is one like the default c# one `Environment.NewLine` which stands for the string `"\r\n"`.
But you can just ignore the empty strings in the following processing of `array`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the new line before splitting

```
text = text.Replace(Environment.NewLine, " ");
```